# NodeJS express server running on Docker image error with "mongodb" module

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, express, mongoose

My goal is to build an express server that connects to MongoDB Atlas then I will push it to the AWS ECR however;
I am getting the following error when running the node server.js command. This error does not show up on my Mac but docker image throws.

Project files are simple as;

- .env
- Dockerfile
- package.json
- server.js

```
/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor/abstract_cursor.js:58
            ...(0, bson_1.pluckBSONSerializeOptions)(options)
            ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js:5:27)
```

my docker command

```
docker build -t users .
```

My dockerfile

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:7.10.1

#Creating a new directory for app files and setting path in the container
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
#setting working directory in the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
#copying the package.json file(contains dependencies) from project source dir to container dir
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
# installing the dependencies into the container
RUN npm install
#copying the source code of Application into the container dir
COPY . /usr/src/app
#container exposed network port number
EXPOSE 3000
#command to run within the container
CMD ["node", "server"]
```

I simplified to determine where the error coming from and my **server.js** file is the following. It doesn't matter whether I use mongoose or mongoclient from the library. It does not allow me to use.

```
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const {mongoose} = require('./db/mongoose');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log(`Started on port ${port}`);
});

module.exports = {app};
```

I manually connect to image with Docker GUI then type node server. It gives me this message.
[my error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HupdO.png)

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Isn't node:7.10 version too old to use?

Comment: Thanks  @Anatoly 
I changed the node version as 16 and build succeed.
`FROM mhart/alpine-node:16`
Issue is fixed now.